# How can I know what Ruby standard libraries I need to explicitly require?

Tags: ruby

I've been looking at the [Ruby Standard Library Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/) for 1.9.3. I'm wondering how I can find out which libraries I need to explicitly require.

For example, I have been told I need to explicitly require the `json` library, but not `rubygems`, although they both appear in the standard library list.

Is there another place I can look for information about the requirements, or even a pry/irb command I can run to see what is already 'required'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every library has to be required/loaded, if you want to use it.

Performance-wise, `require` is smart and will not load libraries if they're already loaded.

However, if you want to check if a library is required you should see the top-level namespace it defines and check if this is defined in your current scope. For example open an IRB session and do:

```
defined? JSON  # => nil (it's not loaded)
require 'json' # => true (load it)
defined? JSON  # => "constant" (it's loaded)
require 'json' # => false (it's already loaded, so it's not loaded it again)
```

Comment: Ruby, like most languages, has a list of classes/modules it loads automatically, whether you ask for them or not, simply because you're going to need them 99% of the time for even a trivial program. Those don't need to be explicitly loaded. The easy way to tell is to run the application during development, and Ruby will tell you if it needs you to `require` something. It's not like the earth will stop if the program can't find what it needs, just add that line and rerun until your program runs correctly. It's part of the development/debugging cycle. Don't think you have to require everything.

Answer (score 2):

It usually doesn't hurt to require things anyway. If they've already been loaded, in general terms, the `require` statement has no effect.

Some core library components are either loaded automatically or autoloaded by referencing their top-level symbol. This list varies from one version of Ruby to another.