# why I received the error "uninitialized constant SecureRandom?

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and using the following

```
puts SecureRandom.uuid
```

but I received the error

```
uninitialized constant SecureRandom
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add a `require` statement in the beginning of the file:

```
require 'securerandom'
```

Comment: No, it's part of Ruby standard library: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Comment: I thought only need to use require when we use gem; for standard library, why do we  need to use require?

Comment: Ohh... I'm afraid I'm not in position to answer that question - I just don't know. Maybe it's worth posting another question in SO regarding that matter?

Comment: It appears it is purely only for performance reasons. Please, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15479299/4381282) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to require ruby library of securerandom to run this method

```
require 'securerandom'
```